# Converter doesn't work with a @ViewScoped

Tags: jsf, null, converters, session-scope, view-scope

i'm facing a problem with a Converter. In my xhtml file, i have a selectOneMenu with a list of object and i want to set an object in my managedBean.

If my managedBean has @SessionScoped, the object in the managedbean is filled but if the managedeban has @ViewScoped, the converter is never use and my object is null.

how to fix this problem ?

Xhtml :

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{rechercheBean.role}" converter="#{typConverter}">
    <f:selectItems id="item" value="#{typBean.roles}" var="r" itemLabel="#{r.valeur}" itemValue="#{r}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

typConverter :

```
public class TypConverter implements Converter{
    @EJB
    private TypFacadeLocal  TypBean;

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue.trim().equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            try {
                Integer id = Integer.parseInt(submittedValue);
                Typ typ = new Typ();
                typ = TypBean.find(id);
                return typ;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Typ non valide"));
            }
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return "";
        }
        else {
            return String.valueOf(((Typ) value).getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Tx a lot

Comment: The cause of the problem is not visible in the code posted so far. Please post an SSCCE.

Comment: There is no code error in this problem... My object in the managedBean stay null when the managedBean is @ViewScoped. If i put a breakpoint in the TypConverter, it's never use in this Scope (contrarty with @SessionScoped)

Comment: I understood that. I was just basically telling that the code which you posted so far looks all fine and thus the cause of your concrete problem cannot be found/understood based on the given code. You need to provide some more context/code so that we can spot the real cause. An SSCCE flavored snippet would be the most ideal (for JSF, that's basically the **smallest possible** XHTML file and backing bean class which we could just copy'n'paste'n'run without any changes to see the problem ourselves).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the component c:when. With the attribut renderer of the component , there is no problem.